# How to get the value of all cells in a jqGrid selected row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

With the underlying code I get the value of a single cell and do a search, I get all the cell values I want and do a search

I do not want a single cell value I want all the values in the column.

Is there anybody who can help me with this?

```
        ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){
        var grid=$('#grid');
        var cm = $("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
        var colName = cm[iCol]["name"];
        var cellvalue = $("#grid").jqGrid("getCell", rowid, iCol);
        $('#gs_' + colName).val(cellvalue);
        grid[0].triggerToolbar();
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you actually want to get - the values of the selected row (as described in the short question) or the values of certain column (as described in the body of your question).

Anyway it is a good idea to look into the documentation method list of jqGrid. In case of [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) the [documentation is here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#method-list)

To get the row values use getRowData method

```
var rowvalues = $("#grid").jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
```

To get the column values use getCol method

```
var colName = cm[iCol]["name"];
var colvalues = $("#grid").jqGrid("getCol", colName);
```

For detailed description of parameters look at the documentation link provided

EDIT: In your case to do what you want the code for double click row can look like this:

```
  ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
    var cm = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    var cmvalues = $(this).jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);
    $.each(cm, function(i,n){
        if(!n.hidden) {
            $('#gs_'+n.name).val( cmvalues[n.name])
        }
    });
    this.triggerToolbar();
  },
```

In order search to work correct the date field should contain equal option for searching - i.e. :

```
{
    name: 'invdate',
    width: 90,
    sorttype: "date",
    formatter: 'date',
    formatoptions: {
      newformat: 'm/d/Y',
      srcformat: 'Y-m-d'
    },
    searchoptions : { sopt['eq'] }
  }
```

Comment: I want to move all selected row values to the checkboxes in their respective columns.
Below is a sample of the table that I am working on.
On this sample it works like this; When I choose a cell on the row, it moves just the chosen cell's value to the checkbox.
Values on the row should moved at the same time with one double-click.
[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/horusmedya/ejnrtocw/240/)

Comment: @Horus, please look at my edited answer. For the condition `if(!n.hidden)` it is a good to add another if the field is searchable - i.e search is true

Comment: It works great, it was very important to me thank you.